# Program only reads last line of text file

Tags: java, text, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to test my program to see if each line in my text document is being stored. For some reason, only the last line is being stored and printed. I tried looking at a similar question someone had, but the solution for that didn't work. Is there any way I can fix this?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class employeeDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        try {
            File file = new File("tester.txt");
            Scanner readFile = new Scanner(file);
            Employee employee2014[] = new Employee[10];
            Employee employee2015[] = new Employee[10];

            int indexEmployee2014 = 0;
            int indexEmployee2015 = 0;

            while(readFile.hasNext()) {
                String year = readFile.next();
                String employeeTitle = readFile.next();
                String employeeName = readFile.next();
                double monthlySalary = readFile.nextDouble();

                if(employeeTitle.equalsIgnoreCase("Employee")) {
                    Employee employee = new Employee(employeeName, monthlySalary);
                    if(year.equals("2014")) {
                        employee2014[indexEmployee2014++] = employee;
                    }
                    if(year.equals("2015")) {
                        employee2015[indexEmployee2015++] = employee;
                    }
                }

                if(employeeTitle.equalsIgnoreCase("Salesman")) {
                    double annualSales = readFile.nextDouble();
                    Salesman salesman = new Salesman(employeeName, monthlySalary, annualSales);
                    if(year.equals("2014")) {
                        employee2014[indexEmployee2014++] = salesman;
                    }
                    if(year.equals("2015")) {
                        employee2015[indexEmployee2015++] = salesman;
                    }
                }

                if(employeeTitle.equalsIgnoreCase("Executive")) {
                    double stockPrice = readFile.nextDouble();
                    Executive executive = new Executive(employeeName, monthlySalary, stockPrice);
                    if(year.equals("2014")) {
                        employee2014[indexEmployee2014++] = executive;
                    }
                    if(year.equals("2015")) {
                        employee2015[indexEmployee2015++] = executive;
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < indexEmployee2015; i++) {
                System.out.print(employee2015[i]);
            }
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Text file

```
2014 Employee Baker,John 15000
2014 Salesman Stein,Amanda 30000 1100000
2014 Executive Kettner,Jessica 53
2015 Employee Edwards,Zach 20000
2015 Salesman Douglas,Shelby 45000 2345
2015 Executive Matthews,Correy 67000 48
```

Comment: Why is Jessica Kettner's salary only $53?  This sounds like a sex discrimination lawsuit waiting to happen.  (Answering this may also solve your problem.)

Comment: I would assume that `System.out.print(employee2015[i]);` means to print out a 2015 employee.  So it looks like your program is doing exactly what you're telling it to.

Comment: OK, that solved it. Thanks!